# Why does sizeof a reference type give you the sizeof the type?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

According to the standard, in [expr.sizeof] (5.3.3.2) we get:

> When applied to a reference or a reference type, the result is the size of the referenced type.

This seems to go along with the fact that references are unspecified [dcl.ref] (8.3.2.4):

> It is unspecified whether or not a reference requires storage

But it seems pretty strange to me to have this kind of inconsistency within the language. Regardless of whether or not the reference requires storage, wouldn't it be important to be able to determine how much size the reference uses? Seeing these results just seems wrong:

```
sizeof(vector<int>) == 24
sizeof(vector<int>*) == 8
sizeof(vector<int>&) == 24
sizeof(reference_wrapper<vector<int>>) == 8
```

What is the reasoning behind wanting `sizeof(T&) == sizeof(T)` by definition?

Comment: I agree that there is inconsistency here, but this is how reference types are defined. References represent the object that they refer to. Performing an operation of an object should have the same result as performing the same operation on a reference to that object. If C++ had a better declaration syntax, I think it'd be better if there were two different types of declaration, like `obj vector<int> v;` and `ref vector<int> vref;`, which I think would be clearer, but this is not the world we live in.

Comment: "wouldn't it be important to be able to determine how much size the reference uses?" - you can determine it: since the reference **is** the object, it uses the same amount of storage as the referenced object. There's no inconsistency here.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant The inconsistency is that references are treated differently to every other type modifier (also because you can't have references to references). It may not be too horrific, but it *is* an inconsistency. Similarly, there are inconsistencies with array types too.

Comment: @JosephMansfield it's not an inconsistency, it's an **exception.** An inconsistency would be something that would cause self-contradictions in the standard, which this treatment of references does not.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Alright. Why the exception? An assigned `T* const` also is the object.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Both words make sense in this sentence. They're not terms defined by the standard. You clearly understood my meaning.

Comment: @Barry A `T *const` is not the object, it's a pointer to the object. A pointer is a stand-alone entity; it has storage, value, etc. It can be used and manipulated without it referring/pointing to any object at all. A reference, however, cannot exist without its backing object. It's just a name alias for the same object.

Comment: @JosephMansfield I am not trying to split hair or twist your words. Although not defined by the standard, "inconsistency" and "exception" mean different things in English. Inconsistency in a programming language standard (or any other mathematical or related system) is bad and unacceptable, while exceptions are not that bad and often acceptable.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: Sorry, but you are completely wrong.  A reference is NOT the object, it is an alias to it.  It has its own lifetime, and may require its own storage.

Comment: What **should** the value be? References are very underspecified, intentionally. There's no guarantee that they always have the same size, for instance.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Don't you mean scope? Lifetime is a property of objects.

Comment: @MSalters: No, I don't.  References do have lifetime, even though the Standard isn't explicit about it in very many places.  One place is the lifetime of reference non-static data members (matches the lifetime of the containing object).  Another is in the closures of capture-by-reference lambdas (the captured entity is the reference itself, not the object it refers to, and the lifetime of the entity is quite important).

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Put a reference in a struct and check the size of the struct.

Comment: BTW, the Standard is very clear that references bind to memory, not objects.  A reference can exist before an object is created, and continue to exist after the object is destroyed, and legally be used in limited ways.  Additionally it can be used to access a new object of identical type created at the same memory location.  None of these would be true if the reference actually were the object.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The choice is somewhat arbitrary, and trying to fully justify either option will lead to circular metaphysical arguments.

The intent of a reference is to be (an alias for) the object itself; under that reasoning it makes sense for them both to have the same size (and address), and that is what the language specifies.

The abstraction is leaky - sometimes a reference has its own storage, separate from the object - leading to anomolies like those you point out. But we have pointers for when we need to deal with a "reference" as a separate entity to the object.

Comment: +1 best layman explanation of reference vs pointer I've seen. And you didn't even need to mention pointers ;)

Comment: It is worth noting that *a non-const variable is already a (logical) reference.* At its heart it is a name for an address. A reference is another name for the same address; it is an alias. (More systematic languages like Algol68 made that clear). Now C and C++ *de-reference normal variables automatically* -- but not "aliases" -- when they are arguments. That is, after `void f(int); int i;` both `f(1)` and `f(i)` are equally valid although the latter should be a type violation (or else e.g. `f(&i)` should be equally valid).  That is the actual peculiarity.

Answer (score 18):

**Argument 1:** A reference should be a synonym of your object hence the interface of the reference should be exactly the same as the interface of the object, also all operators should work in the same way on object and on reference (except type operators).

It will make sense in the following code:

```
MyClass a;
MyClass& b = a;
char a_buf[sizeof(a)];
char b_buf[sizeof(b)]; // you want b_buf be the same size as a_buf
memcpy(&a, a_buf, sizeof(a));
memcpy(&b, b_buf, sizeof(b)); // you want this line to work like the above line
```

**Argument 2:** From C++ standard's point of view references are something under the hood and it even doesn't say if they occupy memory or not, so it cannot say how to get their size.

**How to get reference size:** Since by all compilers references are implemented by help of constant pointers and they occupy memory, there is a way to know their size.

```
class A_ref
{A& ref;}
sizeof(A_ref);
```

Comment: This explains why `sizeof` on a reference should give the size of the referent's type... but not why `sizeof` a reference type should do that.

Comment: @BenVoigt `b` is declared as `MyClass&`, so it makes sense (to me, anyway) that `sizeof(b)` and `sizeof(MyClass&)` give the same result. Explaining why one of the two gives `sizeof(MyClass)` should be sufficient, I think.

Comment: @BenVoigt please see my second argument.

Comment: `sizeof (A_ref)` doesn't tell you whether there's any padding, though.  And `A_ref` isn't standard-layout, so you can't look at the offset to a member placed after the reference, either.

Comment: @BenVoigt since I wrote above standard doesn't tell anything about reference size, so my suggestion of getting its size of course for the usage in practice, and it is good enough for that.

Comment: @Mihran Hovsepyan :  {A& ref;} should be {A_ref& ref}, as the class name is A_ref.

Comment: @Rndp13 I meant A& ref I didn't mean A_ref& ref. That class intened for calculating the size of references to A not to A_ref.

Answer (score 3):

It's not particularly important to know how much storage a reference requires, only the change in storage requirements caused by adding a reference.  And that you can determine:

```
struct with
{
    char c;
    T& ref;
};

struct without
{
    char c;
};

return sizeof (with) - sizeof (without);
```

Comment: When would this be important to know?

Comment: @MobyDisk: Because it can have big effects on performance.  Processor cache can hold a lot more of datatype `without`, probably 8 or 16 times as many, than it can of datatype `with`.

Comment: @BenVoigt your code doesn't take into account alignemnt

Comment: @MihranHovsepyan: I did not claim to be measuring the size of a reference, did I?