# Reference as a only class member gives size 8 for integer

Tags: c++, reference, sizeof, class-members

I came across this scenario while writing a small c++ program to test reference as a class member.

Having reference only as a class member, the program is giving a o/p of 8.
Generally reference gives the size as the particular data type they are of. But why it is 8 here(instead of 4). Please help me in understanding it.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test {
    int &t;
public:
    Test(int &t):t(t) {}
};

int main()
{
    int x = 20;
    Test t1(x);
    int &ref = x;
    cout<<sizeof(ref)<<endl;
    cout<<sizeof(t1)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output -

```
/home/user>./a.out
4
8
```

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26631169/2069064)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[expr.sizeof]

> 2 When applied to a reference or a reference type, the result is the
>   size of the referenced type. When applied to a class, the result is
>   the number of bytes in an object of that class including any padding
>   required for placing objects of that type in an array.

The `sizeof` a reference will return the size of the object referred to, in the case of `sizeof(ref)` this is equivalent to `sizeof(int)`, which on your platform is 4.

Your class on the other hand needs to store a reference to an `int`, the standard doesn't specify how implementations should achieve this but they are commonly, if not universally, stored as pointers behind the scenes. `sizeof(int*)` on your platform is presumably 8, but the details are not important, all you need to know is that `sizeof(Test)` is 8.